# How do you edit the link count on /poll index page?

Tags: 7, polls

In Drupal 7 how do you increase the number of polls listed on domain.com/poll ?

The current limit appears to be 15 polls per page and then there is pagination at the bottom. I would much rather have all my polls listed without pagination.

Is there anyway to increase the number of polls listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard coded in poll module poll.pages.inc file...

```
function poll_page() {
  $polls_per_page = 15;

  $count_select = db_select('node', 'n');
  $count_select->addExpression('COUNT(*)', 'expression');
  $count_select->join('poll', 'p', 'p.nid = n.nid');
  $count_select->condition('n.status', 1);

  // List all polls.
  $select = db_select('node', 'n');
  $select->join('poll', 'p', 'p.nid = n.nid');
  $select->join('poll_choice', 'c', 'c.nid = n.nid');
  $select->addExpression('SUM(c.chvotes)', 'votes');
  $select = $select->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'created'))
    ->fields('p', array('active'))
    ->condition('n.status', 1)
    ->orderBy('n.created', 'DESC')
    ->groupBy('n.nid')
    ->groupBy('n.title')
    ->groupBy('p.active')
    ->groupBy('n.created')
    ->extend('PagerDefault')
    ->limit($polls_per_page)
    ->addTag('node_access');
  $select->setCountQuery($count_select);
  $queried_nodes = $select->execute()
    ->fetchAllAssoc('nid');

  $output = '<ul>';
  foreach ($queried_nodes as $node) {
    $output .= '<li>' . l($node->title, "node/$node->nid") . ' - ' . format_plural($node->votes, '1 vote', '@count votes') . ' - ' . ($node->active ? t('open') : t('closed')) . '</li>';
  }
  $output .= '</ul>';
  $output .= theme('pager');
  return $output;
}
```

Override the menu item using [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) and change the callback as well as setting which you can see in first line of above function using a custom module.. Otherwise use views to build your own page which will display polls...

Comment: Thanks so much Anil, I really appreciate you taking the time to provide this answer. It seems strange to me that this is not something that Drupal allows the user to set!